# Automated donation script, unable to display price.

Tags: php

I am trying to create an automated donation script, but I'm facing one last error. I want to display the amount of points a user is able to get for a certain amount of dollars, but it won't display the amount of dollars it costs for an x amount of points. I'll post both the codes below.

```
$donation_types = array(
1 => 100,
5 => 500,
10 => 1000,
15 => 1500,
25 => 2500,
50 => 5000,
100 => 10000
);
```

// this is the amount of dollars a certain amount of points cost, ex: 100$ will get you 10000 points.

```
<?php
foreach ($donation_types as $usd_amount => $dp_amount) {
?>

<option value="<?php echo $usd_amount; ?>">&#36;<?php echo sprintf('%.2n', $usd_amount); ?> - <?php echo number_format($dp_amount, 0); ?> DP</option>
```

// this is where I want the price to be displayed for the amount of points. As you can see below it doesn't display the price it costs just the dollar sign.

I'm not allowed to post images, but here's a link to the image: http://puu.sh/1jttY

Is there a solution for this?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `sprintf('%.2n', $usd_amount)` with `sprintf('%.2f', $usd_amount)` or some other template